# Should we have a Salesforce-support tag?

Tags: discussion

I want to understand the StackExchange community member's thoughts on having a tag for questions that would need Salesforce support's intervention. Currently, a few of us are already monitoring questions here for platform-related issues/limitations/GACKs/release-related queries. How feasible is having a tag for monitoring such issues closely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we should not have a `salessforce-support` tag, and we have gone to great lengths to block similar tags. Any tag that has `salesforce` in the name is rife for abuse by our new members. The unfortunate reality is that it gets added to way too many posts, even if it is carefully scoped to only be relevant in certain circumstances. I am quite sure if we were to create this tag, at least 90% of our posts by new users would have it added. If you think about it from the perspective of someone who's new here, it seems natural that their question should be tagged with `salesforce-support`, and they won't read the tag description. I vehemently oppose addition of this tag.

You can tag questions with `gack` if you wish to track gacks, `release` for release related issues, etc.

Comment: In the last sentence of your first paragraph, I think you meant to type "vehemently oppose." :)

Comment: Good catch, thanks!